# What are the criteria for the Battle Pass "eliminate enemy in place" challenges?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

After purchasing the Battle Pass, I unlocked several challenges. Some of these were

> "Eliminate Enemies in (Dusty, Retail, Greasy, Tomato etc.)"

What are the criteria for this? If you snipe a player who is out of Dusty, will it still count as a kill? If you are out of Dusty, but snipe a player in Dusty, will that count as a kill? Do you both need to be in Dusty? If you are right next to dusty (5 to 10 meters) will it count as your kill?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the videos I watched, I would say that only you have to be at that location, but I can't tell for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the rule seems to be that you and the person you kill must be within 20-30m of the location. I know that I was standing on the bridge by tomato town and sniped someone in the restaurant, and it didn't count as a kill, but when I was around 20m outside tomato and I killed someone who was directly next to me, I did get the kill